# Is it possible to use DateTime.Now where I really require DateTime.UtcNow?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there some way to force `DateTime.Now` to always return `DateTime.UtcNow` for application?

--edit
My intention:
I have big datetime-very-sensitive application. I cant rewrite all places where it is (time consuming). Programmers sometimes in time pressure forgot to use utcnow.

Comment: You could create your own static DateTime class ;) But I guess that's all you can do

Comment: By "arbitrarily", you don't mean randomly? But why can't you just call `DateTime.UtcNow` directly?

Comment: Move to Iceland or Burkina Faso? :) On a more serious note, do you know of [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/)? Would be a serious abuse of a testing framework though.

Comment: Set time zone of the machine to UTC :)

Comment: @Dominik would also need to account for daylight savings and such.

Comment: The question is, why do you want to have this behaviour? What's the intention behind it?

Comment: Abusing mocking could provide a temporary solution, but bite the bullet, and do the right thing and change the `DateTime.Now` calls to `DateTime.UtcNow` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option for you is to use a mock to return datetime in your application.

For unittesting or other function you can use a custom DateTime

Take a look to this:

http://blog.coreycoogan.com/2009/06/07/mocking-datetime-now/

Answer (score 0):

> I cant rewrite all places where it is (time consuming)

Yes, and that takes like one minute (replace file in files) plus your unit tests telling you what fails.

The alternative is to mess up the behavior for new parts of the program where the user MAY NEED the local time for whatever reason. Seriously, sit down and clean up the program.

DateTime.Now is static, so it has to be in this form, finding that is trivial. fixing those cases will be relatively, except you have to add stuff like conversion routines for input and output - and you have to do that in any case.